COM Error while accessing Office 365 EXCEL from code
I am getting the following error when using Office Interop to access excel from office365.
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070490 Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490).
I re-installed office365 recently and this error started happening.
When I installed the apps - the AppID was CLSID {00020812-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}, but the interop was looking for CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} so I renamed the AppID in the registry as per the instruction from Link.
I still keep getting the same error, I gave permission to interactive and to my domain username but still no luck.
Any inputs to fix this is greatly appreciated.

I renamed the AppID in the registry: You probably shouldn't have done that -  don't believe everything you read on the interet.. Hope you performed a backup before you changed it.

The following may be of interest: Considerations for unattended automation of Office in the Microsoft 365 for unattended RPA environment and Considerations for server-side Automation of Office

renaming the AppID didnt cause any major issue. I was able to revert back/ also able to re-install office365

00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046 is Excel's Application object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object). 00020812-0000-0000-C000-000000000046 is Excel's Global object which is note technically the sam. It's very probably a deployment/setup/install issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484297/office-word-interop-fails-with-element-not-found-error
